# UpdateOrCreate conditional data as input

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, refactoring

I have this code, that results in two queries.

```
$profile = $profile_class::updateOrCreate([
        'user_id' => $user->id,
    ], 
    [
        'data' => $profile_data,
]);

if($request->type == 'volontario' && $request->filled('association_id')) {
        $profile->association_id = $request->association_id;
        $profile->association_token = uniqid(md5($user->id));
        $profile->save();
}
```

Is there any approach for only executing one query to the db?

Comment: Did my answer help your problem, else i'm willingly to dig deeper?

Answer (score 0):

You can just change the data that should be updated, depended on if your request is in the correct state. For this to work, `association_id` and `association_token` should be fillable.

```
$fillData = [
    'data' => $profile_data,
];

if($request->type == 'volontario' && $request->filled('association_id')) {
    $fillData['association_id'] = $request->association_id;
    $fillData['association_token'] = uniqid(md5($user->id));
}

$profile = $profile_class::updateOrCreate([
        'user_id' => $user->id,
    ],
    $fillData
);
```